# Limit of integral without analytical solution

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

I am trying to solve the limit of this integral:

\begin{equation}
\lim_{z \longrightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \varphi \left( \xi - K_{1} \right) \Phi \left( \frac{z - K_{3}}{\xi} + K_{3} \right) \mathrm{d \xi}.
\end{equation}

Can I bring the limit inside the integral? I think that the monotonic convergence of a sequence of real numbers theorem can help, but I am not sure about it.

Comment: You might want to put a $d\xi$

Comment: Sorry, I corrected my mistake

Answer (score 1):

If $\Phi$ is bounded and $\varphi$ is integrable, the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem says you can bring the limit inside.

Comment: I think this is a sufficient answer~